# Jquery scroll to bottom of a visualforce page on buttonclick

Tags: jquery

I have a button that on clicking calls a webservice and displays a list of record below that button. I'm trying to scroll down to the bottom most part of the visualforce page, everytime the button is clicked. Any reference would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick javascript function to do this:

`window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);`

where the parameters are the coordinates for x and y, respectively.

Documentation of the function: [Window.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollTo)